# Cannot populate when I use Foreign key in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I tried to join three documents in mongodb using mongoose in nodejs, but unfortunately this error occurs. My mongoose version is 6.2.3

**Declaring Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const declaringSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    cniDeclaring: { type: Number, required: true },
    father: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Father',
        required: true,
    },
    mother: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Mother',
        required: true,
    },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    surname: { type: String, required: true },
    birthDay: { type: Date, required: true },
    birthPlace: { type: String, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    relationShipDeclared: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: Number, required: true },
   
    request: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Request',
    }],
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Declaring', declaringSchema);
```

**Declared Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const declaredSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    surname: { type: String, required: true },
    father: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Father',
    },
    mother: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Mother',
    },
    birthDay: { type: Date, required: true },
    birthPlace: { type: String, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    nationality: { type: String, required: true },
    request: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Request',
    },
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Declared', declaredSchema);
```

**Father Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const fatherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    cniFather: { type: Number, required: true },
    nameP: { type: String, required: true },
    surname: { type: String, required: true },
    birthDay: { type: Date, required: true },
    birthPlace: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: Number, required: true },
    occupation: { type: String, required: true },
    declaring: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Declaring',
    }],
    declared: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Declared',
    }],
}); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Father', fatherSchema);
```

Now I want to get all the fathers back

```
const Father = require('../models/Father');

exports.createFather = (req, res, next) => {
    const father = new Father({
        ...req.body
    });
    father.save()
      .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Father created !'}))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error })
    );
}

exports.getAllFathers = (req, res, next) => {
  Father.find()
    .populate('declarings')
    .populate('declareds')
    .exec((err, res) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });     

};
```

and I have the following error:

**MongooseError: Cannot populate path `declarings` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.**

Comment: the field in `Father` Schema is `declaring` not `declarings`  also for `declared`

Comment: you can use $lookup in aggregate query. that will populate nested referenced schema